# Why did I got no detail about my AWS IAM identity? Unknown output type: JSON

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

From command line,I tried to show my current config.

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

Shows empty line and

```
Unknown output type: JSON
```

I check my config

```
[default]
region = eu-west-1
output = JSON
source_profile = monzo-konzo
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your output format is in entire capitals. As per the documentation it should be `json`.

For more information about output types take a read of [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html).